# Add a new page at runtime in WPF on button click

Tags: wpf

In my application I need to create a new XAML page/usercontrol at runtime. The use case is like:

1. User Clicks on add page button on the main window.
2. A new XAML page gets added to the application.
3. User can design the page by adding controls from a custom tool bar and save the page.
4. User can also add event handler to navigate between pages.

Please let me know how can I go about this.

Comment: You are pretty much asking for an entire feature ... please share code samples of the things your tried, and where you encountered any problems ...

Comment: This site is *not* somewhere that developers go to have their work done for them.

Comment: I am not asking for the complete feature . I just mentioned a use case for the complete feature. I just need a help on point 1 - User Clicks on add page button on the main window.